# Why does Slack not have a tray icon any more?

Tags: system-tray, i3-wm

I've installed the Slack snap; recently, its tray icon stopped displaying. Instead there's just a blank space – though if I right-click it, the Slack menu still opens. All my other tray icons are working fine.

Why has Slack's icon disappeared, and how can I get it back?

I'm using i3 with i3bar to display tray icons, on Ubuntu 18.04. Slack is currently at version 3.3.7.

Comment: I do not have this problem on KDE, so I would guess that it is an issue with the i3bar implementation. I suggest comparing with other implementations of the system tray.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a problem present since months in the Snap version of Slack. One possible workaround is using the DEB version, the other is restarting the system until it works. Usually, the latter does not work.

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I installed slack using snap. Then, I downloaded the .deb for 3.3.8 (same version installed before using snap), removed the one I installed using snap and finally installed the .deb. after that, tray icon appeared.

(BTW, I'm using i3wm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And it's been a problem for years, actually. One of a million reasons Snap is terrible. (https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/slack-snap-window-has-no-icon/3589/54)